# Operation satysfaying b*(b*a)=a=(a*b)*b for all a and b must be commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, binary-operations, magma

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $*$ operation defined on elements of $X$ such that for $a, b$ from $X$ there is $(a*b)*b=b*(b*a)=a$. Prove that operation $*$ is commutative. Exercise is taken from the "Introduction to algebra" by Kostrikin.

Comment: Is the operator known to be associative? Invertible?

Comment: @StellaBiderman No, there are no additional assumptions.

Answer (score 9):

$a=(a(ba))(ba)=(ba)((ba)a)=(ba)b$.

Thus, $ab=((ba)b)b=ba$